# TBitBtn Font Style on MouseEnter Event

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have an application having one TBitBtn as "BitBtn1". Initially BitBtn1 Font Style is "[]" i.e. Normal. If my Code is as follows :

```
procedure TForm00001.BitBtn00003MouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      BitBtn1.Font.Style :=fsBold;
    end;
```

it gives an error. Please help me so that I can change TBitBtn Font Style as Bold on "MouseEnter Event".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Font style is a set. Correct syntax is

```
BitBtn1.Font.Style := [fsBold];
```

It is a set so that you can apply multiple styles, for example

```
BitBtn1.Font.Style := [fsBold, fsItalic];
```